# Yii2 display data after join

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have joined 2 table, now I want to show the name of categories in field `<th>Categories name</th>`. How can I do that with `<?php foreach ($posts as $post){ ?>` ? Do i render like `<?=$post->categories.name?>` ? I'm stuck here.

Thank you.

My controller:

```
  public function actionIndex()
{

     $query = posts::find()->leftJoin('categories', 'posts.cate_id = categories.id');
     $cates = Categories::find()->all();
     $posts= $query->orderBy(['create_date' => SORT_DESC])->all();
     $images = Images::find()->all();
     $searchModel = new PostsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'posts' => $posts,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'cates' => $cates,
            'images' => $images,
    ]);
}
```

My view:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Create Date</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post){ ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $post->id ?></td>

     <th><?= Html::a($post->name, ['post/view', 'id'=>$post->id]) ?></th>

    <td><?= $post->create_date ?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
     </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the categories just as with posts. Its the same principle.

```
foreach($posts as $post)
    foreach($post->categories as $category)
        echo $category->name;
```

This is based on the assumption you have defined the proper relations in the model.

I.e. through foreign key:

```
public function getCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::className(), ['post_id' => 'id']);
}
```

You seem to have it the other way around. You can have category_id in post, but then its limited to one category. Unless, you store the ids in the field seperated by a delimeter. But that option requires a bit more work.